# Open modal / offcanvas with a single button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to open my favorites sidebar with a single click on my keyboard. So when pressing "f" I want the sidebar modal to open. Now it opens like this:

```
<a href="#" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#favorites">
    Open Favorites
</a>
```

I am unsure how to do this with jquery, I have been trying like this but without success:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
 if (e.keyCode == "s") {
   $('#favorites').show();
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show/hide the offcanvas from the JavaScript you can use an [offcanvas instance](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/offcanvas/#methods) eg: `const bsOffcanvas = new bootstrap.Offcanvas('#favorites');`. Which has methods like `hide`, `show`, `toggle`. Also the `keyCode` for f is 70. So, when the key code is 70 you can show the offcanas with `bsOffcanvas.show();`. See the following example:

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  console.log(e.keyCode);
  if (e.keyCode == 70) {
    const bsOffcanvas = new bootstrap.Offcanvas('#favorites');
    bsOffcanvas.show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#"  type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#favorites">
    Open Favorites
</a>


<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" tabindex="-1" id="favorites" >
  <div class="offcanvas-header">
    <h5 id="offcanvasRightLabel">Favorites Offcanvas</h5>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="offcanvas-body">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes works like a charm, thanks for the explanation!